# Android Paging 3 library loading infinitely without scroll with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-paging

I'm attempting to make a paged list of books using Jetpack Compose and Android's Paging 3 library.  I am able to make the paged list and get the data fine, but the `load()` function of my paging data source is being called infinitely, without me scrolling the screen.

My paging data source looks like this:

```
class GoogleBooksBookSource @Inject constructor(
    private val googleBooksRepository: GoogleBooksRepository,
    private val query: String
): PagingSource<Int, Book>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Book> {
        val position = params.key ?: 0
        return try {
            val response = googleBooksRepository.searchForBookStatic(query, position)
            if (response is Result.Success) {
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = response.data.items,
                    prevKey = if (position == 0) null else position - 1,
                    nextKey = if (response.data.totalItems == 0) null else position + 1
                )
            } else {
                LoadResult.Error(Exception("Error loading paged data"))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("PagingError", e.message.toString())
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Book>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
            val anchorPage = state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)
            anchorPage?.prevKey?.plus(1) ?: anchorPage?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the UI:

```
Column() {
    // other stuff
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
        content = {
            for (i in 0 until searchResults.itemCount) {
                searchResults[i]?.let { book ->
                    item {
                        BookCard(
                            book = book,
                            navigateToBookDetail = { navigateToBookDetail(book.id) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

As far as I can tell, the data loads correctly and in the correct order, but when I log the API request URLs, it's making infinite calls with an increasing `startIndex` each time.  That would be fine if I was scrolling, since Google Books searches often return thousands of results, but it does this even if I don't scroll the screen.

Comment: can try to debug and see if `getRefreshKey()` is running all the time? I guess your code is correct just this function seems have some problem

Comment: `getRefreshKey()` is not being called repeatedly, but `load()` is.  Without me scrolling the screen, the `state.anchorPosition` in `onRefreshKey()` is in the hundreds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was the way I was creating elements in the `LazyColumn` - it natively supports `LazyPagingItem` but I wasn't using that.  Here is the working version:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
    state = listState,
    content = {
        items(pagedSearchResults) { book ->
            book?.let {
                BookCard(
                    book = book,
                    navigateToBookDetail = { navigateToBookDetail(book.id) }
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original example, you have to use **peek** to check for non-null and access the list as you do only **inside** item block, which is lazy. Otherwise the paging capabilities will be lost and it will load the entire dataset in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The `items` method in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70187100/9433458) is deprecated from version 3.2.0 of the paging-compose library ([changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/paging#3.2.0)). You should use something like the below:

```
items(
    count = pagedSearchResults.itemCount,
    key = pagedSearchResults.itemKey {  /* Your Key */ },
    contentType = pagedSearchResults.itemContentType { /* Your ContentType */ }
) {
    /* Content */
}
```

which `itemKey` and `itemContentType` are extension functions in the paging-compose library.